# Using Apply() Function to a matrix

Tags: r, function, matrix, apply

Given a table I need to use `apply()` to find t the correlation between each one of the 8 variables in the `state.x77` matrix and the `Population` variable. state.x77 is a built in matrix with 8 columns.

I had to first create a function called cor_var due to the instructions and then have to use apply(). So here is my input:

```
cor_var=function(v1,v2=state.x77[,"Income"]){cor(v1,v2)}
apply(mat,2,cor_var,v2=state.x77[,"Population"])
```

the v2 is the extra optional argument for apply() ... argument, so this should work but it is returning `Error in cor(v1, v2) : incompatible dimensions`. Any help on where I am wrong would be appreciated. I have to use cor_var and apply two functions btw, can't use lappy or mapply.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible, example.  What is `mat`?.  If i do `mat <- matrix(1:100, nrow = 50);apply(mat,2,cor_var,v2=state.x77[,"Population"])#
[1] -0.0515002 -0.0515002`

Comment: I'm not getting an error with `apply(state.x77,2,cor_var,v2=state.x77[,"Population"])`, so you have probably messed up in your creation of mat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
apply(state.x77,2,function(x) cor(x, state.x77[,"Income"]))


#Population     Income Illiteracy   Life Exp     Murder    HS Grad      Frost       Area 
# 0.2082276  1.0000000 -0.4370752  0.3402553 -0.2300776  0.6199323  0.2262822  0.3633154
```

Comment: oh dang, i was so dumb... i used mat another variable.... but yes thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
apply(mat,2,cor_var,v2=state.x77[,"Population"])
```